# how to use SSE to process array of ints, using a condition

Tags: c++, sse

I'm new to SSE, and limited in knowledge. I'm trying to vectorize my code (C++, using gcc), which is actually quite simple. 
I have an array of unsigned ints, and I only check for elements that are >=, or <= than some constant. As result, I need an array with elements that passed condition.
I'm thinking to use 'mm_cmpge_ps' as a mask, but this construct work over floats not ints!? :(

any suggestion, help is very much appreciated.

Comment: See `_mm_cmpgt_epi32`. It is a signed comparison, but you can work around that. But do you want compaction, or just put some other number in the positions that didn't pass the check?

Comment: well, if it hurts performance, that I can live without compaction, will simply put '0', or you have a better suggestion?

Comment: `gcc -O3` with a suitable `-march=...` flag vectorizes `void f(unsigned *p,unsigned l, int n){ for(int i=0;i<n;++i) p[i]=(p[i]<=l)?p[i]:0; }` (if you tell it more about the alignment of p and the parity of n, it will help it generate better code), so you can just look at the generated asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to just mask out (i.e. set to 0) all non-matching ints. e.g.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>    // SSE2 intrinsics

for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 4)
{
    __m128i v = _mm_load_si128(&a[i]);
    __m128i vcmp0 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(v, _mm_set1_epi32(MIN_VAL - 1));
    __m128i vcmp1 = _mm_cmplt_epi32(v, _mm_set1_epi32(MAX_VAL + 1));
    __m128i vcmp = _mm_and_si128(vcmp0, vcmp1);
    v = _mm_and_si128(v, vcmp);
    _mm_store_si128(&a[i], v);
}
```

Note that `a` needs to be 16 byte aligned and `N` needs to be a multiple of 4 - if these constraints are a problem then it's not too hard to extend the code to cope with this.

Comment: which header should I use in order to try this code (GCC)? __m256i is a new type that I first see it here. Are this instructions AVX? my compiler fails to include gmmintrin.h for AVX. 
Also, can you explain what does 'MIN_VAL - 1' do? as well as MAX_VAL - 1?

Comment: can you explain, why are you using once  __m128i vcmp, and __m256i for comparing vectors?

Comment: Sorry - typos - I've been working with AVX/AVX2 a lot lately so my fingers were automatically typing 256 instead of 128 - fixed now. I've also added the relevant #include for SSE2.

Comment: I just added an answer which used your code for one function.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the set1's were outside the loop, or do compilers do that automatically these days?

Comment: @harold: I've never found a compiler that fails to optimise this, but yes, if you want to play it safe you could initialise these constant vectors prior to the loop.

Comment: You are assuming that the array is aligned and that N is a multiple of 4. Also, since the OP is using gcc (hopefully a recent one), after `__v4si *b = (__v4si*) a;` the interior of the loop can be rewritten as `__v4si v = *b; *b = v & (v >= MIN_VAL) & (v <= MAX_VAL);`.

Comment: @Marc: true - I should have noted the alignment and array size constraints. I disagree regarding the gcc-specific syntax though on the grounds of portability.

Comment: @PaulR: agreed for portability, but it is so much more readable... Please complain to vendors who don't support a readable syntax.

Comment: @Marc: well the gcc syntax only really works for a small subset of possible SIMD routines - anything beyond a relatively trivial function generally needs to be written with intrinsics anyway, so you have to "bite the bullet" at some point. Also, for trivial functions you can often get auto-vectorization to work.

Comment: @PaulR: it's the same as with scalars, you write `n+1`, not `scalar_plus_int32(n,scalar_load_int32_cst(1))`, for a small subset of operations, and for the others (say factorial) you call a function. Writing vector code with gcc's extension and just a couple intrinsics here and there already helps readability a lot. And it makes it easier to write code that works with SSEx but benefits from SSEy if compiled for it.

Comment: @Marc: yes, I can see the attraction, but the gcc syntax only maps to a subset of SIMD operations - it doesn't handle packing/unpacking, permutations/shuffles, fixed point math, reductions, etc - it's fine for very simple fixed element width stuff, but for most real world SIMD stuff it doesn't really help.

Comment: @PaulR: it does handle permutations via __builtin_shuffle (clang has a slightly different name and syntax). You can even write `vec w={v[1],v[0]};` and gcc will detect the shuffle.

Comment: @Marc: interesting about the shuffle syntax - I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.  Here are three functions.

The first function,`foo_v1`, is based on Paul R's answer.

The second function,`foo_v2`, is based on a popular question today [Fastest way to determine if an integer is between two integers (inclusive) with known sets of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095324/fastest-way-in-c-to-determine-if-an-integer-is-between-two-integers-inclusive/17095543#17095543)

The third function, `foo_v3` uses Agner Fog's vectorclass which I added only to show how much easier and cleaner it is to use his class.  If you don't have the class then just comment out the `#include "vectorclass.h"` line and the `foo_v3` function.  I used `Vec8ui` which means it will use AVX2 if available and break it into two Vec4ui otherwise so you don't have to change your code to get the benefit of AVX2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>                 // SSE4.2
#include "vectorclass.h"

void foo_v1(const int N, int *a, const int MAX_VAL, const int MIN_VAL) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 4) {
        __m128i v = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)&a[i]);
        __m128i vcmp0 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(v, _mm_set1_epi32(MIN_VAL - 1));
        __m128i vcmp1 = _mm_cmplt_epi32(v, _mm_set1_epi32(MAX_VAL + 1));
        __m128i vcmp = _mm_and_si128(vcmp0, vcmp1);
        v = _mm_and_si128(v, vcmp);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&a[i], v);
    }
}

void foo_v2(const int N, int *a, const int MAX_VAL, const int MIN_VAL) {
    //if ((unsigned)(number-lower) < (upper-lower))
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 4) {
        __m128i v = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)&a[i]);
        __m128i dv = _mm_sub_epi32(v, _mm_set1_epi32(MIN_VAL));
        __m128i min_ab = _mm_min_epu32(dv,_mm_set1_epi32(MAX_VAL-MIN_VAL));
        __m128i vcmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(dv,min_ab);
        v = _mm_and_si128(v, vcmp);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&a[i], v);
    }
}

void foo_v3(const int N, int *a, const int MAX_VAL, const int MIN_VAL) {
    //if ((unsigned)(number-lower) < (upper-lower))
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 8) {
        Vec8ui va = Vec8ui().load(&a[i]);
        va &= (va - MIN_VAL) <= (MAX_VAL-MIN_VAL);
        va.store(&a[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    const int N = 16;
    int* a = (int*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(int)*N, 16);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    foo_v2(N, a, 7, 3);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    } printf("\n");
    _mm_free(a);
}
```

Comment: Nice - it would be interesting to benchmark all three - my guess is that there won't be much difference.

Comment: Probably not, I tried to do foo_v2 in less instructions but was not able to.  I wanted to use only _mm_cmplt_epi32 and not _mm_min_epu32 and _mm_cmpeq_epi32.

Comment: No problem, I'm still learning SSE/AVX myself, I suggest looking at the code in the vectorclass.  That can answer 90% of your questions.  The rest you can find on SO.

Comment: is there a way to count the number of such '0' elements using SSE?

Comment: @PaulR, I forgot to mention, that if one has XOP, the >= can be done in one instruction with _mm_comge_epu32(a,b).  That would be one instruction less.

Comment: @NikKovac, why don't you ask that as a question for others to try and answer.  You could probably do it with _mm_movemask_epi8 among other options.

Comment: Yes, there are several neat ways of counting masked (or non-masked) elements - that would make a good (separate) question.

Answer (score 0):

First place to look might be [Intel® Intrinsics Guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-intrinsics-guide)