# Why does branching occur in assembly code while comparing for a number to be in range?

Tags: c++, c, performance, math, optimization

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095324/fastest-way-in-c-to-determine-if-an-integer-is-between-two-integers-inclusive) question and it's accepted answer. I read the comments but I couldn't figure out the reason for the optimization produced.

Why does branching occur in assembly code when using the following code?

```
x >= start && x <= end
```

EDIT:
For clarity, I want to understand the reason of optimization produced by the accepted answer. That as I understand is the branching present in the assembly code produced by the compiler. I want to understand why is there a branch in the produced code.

Comment: Short Circuiting

Comment: @Mysticial I have no idea what that means in this context. I read that in the comments but couldn't understand that. That's why I started this question.

Comment: @Mysticial: But short-circuiting makes no difference here, as there are no observable side-effects.  The compiler would be entitled to implement this with a single branch.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Which is why I didn't make that an answer since I'm not 100% sure either.

Comment: @Jason I am asking about the reason for the optimization produced in the said [question's accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095324/fastest-way-in-c-to-determine-if-an-integer-is-between-two-integers-inclusive). What is the reason for branching produced?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that the linked question has a fundamentally different expression

```
x >= start && x++ <= end
```

It is fundamentally different because the second sub-expression here has a side effect. I'll explain.

Note that `&&` is a [short-circuit operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means that if `x >= start` evaluates to `false`, the machine *can* branch over evaluation of `x <= end`.

More precisely, when the compiler emits instructions for `x >= start && x <= end`, it *can* emit instructions to branch over `x <= end` when `x >= start` evaluates to false.

However, I stress the use of the word *can* in the above statements. The reason for this is because `x <= end` has no side-effects and therefore it doesn't matter if the compiler branches over evaluation of it or not.

But, in the case that the second expression does have side effects the compiler *must* branch over it. Since `&&` is a short-circuit operator, in `a && b`, if `b` has any side effects they *must not* be observed if `a` evaluates to `false`; this is a requirement of short-circuiting in C and most (if not all C-like languages).

So, in particular, when you look at

```
define POINT_IN_RANGE_AND_INCREMENT(p, range) 
    (p <= range.end && p++ >= range.start)
```

note that the second expression `p++ >= range.start` has a side effect. Namely, (post-)incrementing `p` by `1`. But that side effect can only be observed if `p <= range.end` evaluates to `true`. Thus, the compiler *must* branch over evaluation of `p++ >= range.start` if `p <= range.end` evaluates to false.

The reason this results in a branch is because for machine to evaluate that expression, it uses the fact that **if `p <= range.end`** evaluates to `false`, then it automatically knows the entire expression evaluates to `false` and therefore it *should not* evaluate `p++ >= range.start` because it has a side-effect. Thus, it *must* branch over evaluating the second part of the expression. So in the assembly:

```
Ltmp1301:
 ldr    r1, [sp, #172] @ 4-byte Reload
 ldr    r1, [r1]
 cmp    r0, r1
 bls    LBB44_32
 mov    r6, r0         @ if the result of the compare is false 
 b      LBB44_33       @ branch over evaluating the second expression
                       @ to avoid the side effects of p++
LBB44_32:
 ldr    r1, [sp, #188] @ 4-byte Reload
 adds   r6, r0, #1
Ltmp1302:
 ldr    r1, [r1]
 cmp    r0, r1
 bhs    LBB44_36
```

Deep indebtedness to [Oli Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oli-charlesworth) for insightful comments.

Comment: Short-circuiting has better performance, especially when the second condition is hard to evaluate

Comment: @Enigma: If the 2nd condition is trivial to evaluate, then short-circuiting probably results in significantly worse performance.  Which is why I'm surprised the compiler didn't reduce this to a single branch (in the linked question).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Don't think so Oli. Look at the original post. The context is the definition of the macro(?) `POINT_IN_RANGE_AND_INCREMENT(p, range)` and why the compiler emits a branch when that macro is defined as `p <= range.end && p++ >= range.start`.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, I've just spotted that the OP of the linked question only revealed the side-effect much later!  (I was following the answers to that question yesterday.) Nevertheless, the answer to **this** question (as it currently stands) is not "short-circuiting".  But perhaps the question needs to be edited...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What kind of editing? Any confusion regarding the question? I edited it once.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Hmm. I'm not seeing it. I think he's asking why the non-optimized version has the branch, so he can understand why the optimized version is so much better. The non-optimized version *does* have a branch because of short-circuiting. Do you disagree?

Comment: @Zel: Because it turns out that in the linked question, the code isn't `(x > start && x < end)`, it's `(x > start && x++ < end)`, which makes a **huge** difference.

Comment: @Jason That is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: @Jason: In the OP's code, there is no side-effect, so short-circuiting is irrelevant.  In the code in the linked question, there is (as you rightly point out) a side-effect, which *does* make a difference.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Doesn't matter. Short-circuiting still applies.

Comment: @Jason: Not really.  If there is no observable side-effect, the compiler is free to not jump out early (especially as that would be more optimal).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am missing something. I didn't understand your confusion in the present question(not the linked question)

Comment: @Zel: `(x > start && x < end)` is very different behaviourally to `(x > start && x++ < end)`.  The "extra" branching applies to the second version, not what you have posted.

Comment: @Zel The two questions are completely different beasts with regard to what kind of optimizations are possible. The linked question has a side effect in the later part which means the compiler is forced to do the short-circuiting for correctness. If there was no side effect not doing the short-circuiting would result in much better performance.

Comment: There's a difference between "may" and "must" when side effects are present or absent.  If there are no side effects, the compiler may rearrange as it pleases (for speed), but if there are side effects—and there are—the compiler *must not* rearrange.  It might be helpful to include that in the answer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I understand the point you are making. I will edit my answer accordingly. Give me a few minutes, and let me know if it makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Good? Thanks for the comments.