# checking wether an int is not between 2 values

Tags: java

How do i check wether a int is between two values when comparing it in an if statement, similar to this

```
 if (num >= 1 && num <= 100 && bool != false) {System.out.print(true);}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question? Your code seems to already do what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095324/fastest-way-in-c-to-determine-if-an-integer-is-between-two-integers-inclusive?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Well, this looks like it should work. What are you looking for exactly - a more efficient way to do this?

```
int num =0;
if (num >= 1 && num <= 100) {
  //do something             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool != false
```

is very confusing.  Not only is it a double negative, but comparing a boolean value to true or false is redundant.  Neither does the name give any hint as to its purpose.  Something like the following would be clearer.

```
if(checkRange && (num >= 1 && num <= 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

That question is quite weird since the answer is in the code you have provided. To check if the int is between two values just use this code.

```
if(num >= min && num <= max)
```

The more effective way - when you have multiple intervals is to use Interval Tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
int j=3;
for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
    if(j.equals(i)) {
        System.out.println("Given value is between 0-10");
    }
}
```