# SSE2 intrinsics - comparing unsigned integers

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm interested in identifying overflowing values when adding unsigned 8-bit integers, and clamping the result to 0xFF:

```
__m128i m1 = _mm_loadu_si128(/* 16 8-bit unsigned integers */);
__m128i m2 = _mm_loadu_si128(/* 16 8-bit unsigned integers */);

__m128i m3 = _mm_adds_epu8(m1, m2);
```

I would be interested in performing comparison for "less than" on these unsigned integers, similar to `_mm_cmplt_epi8` for signed:

```
__m128i mask = _mm_cmplt_epi8 (m3, m1);
m1 = _mm_or_si128(m3, mask);
```

If an "epu8" equivalent was available, `mask` would have `0xFF` where `m3[i] < m1[i]` (overflow!), `0x00` otherwise, and we would be able to clamp `m1` using the "or", so `m1` will hold the addition result where valid, and `0xFF` where it overflowed.

Problem is, `_mm_cmplt_epi8` performs a signed comparison, so for instance if `m1[i] = 0x70` and `m2[i] = 0x10`, then `m3[i] = 0x80` and `mask[i] = 0xFF`, which is obviously not what I require.

Using VS2012.

I would appreciate another approach for performing this. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, `_mm_adds_epu8` already saturated the result. Identifying where the results saturated are needed for a calculation which is not described here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way of implementing compares for unsigned 8 bit vectors is to exploit `_mm_max_epu8`, which returns the maximum of unsigned 8 bit int elements. You can compare for equality the (unsigned) maximum value of two elements with one of the source elements and then return the appropriate result. This translates to 2 instructions for `>=` or `<=`, and 3 instructions for `>` or `<`.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>    // SSE2

#define _mm_cmpge_epu8(a, b) \
        _mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_max_epu8(a, b), a)

#define _mm_cmple_epu8(a, b) _mm_cmpge_epu8(b, a)

#define _mm_cmpgt_epu8(a, b) \
        _mm_xor_si128(_mm_cmple_epu8(a, b), _mm_set1_epi8(-1))

#define _mm_cmplt_epu8(a, b) _mm_cmpgt_epu8(b, a)

int main(void)
{
    __m128i va = _mm_setr_epi8(0,   0,   1,   1,   1, 127, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255);
    __m128i vb = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 255,   0,   1, 255,   0, 127, 255,   0, 128, 255,   0, 254, 255,   0, 255);

    __m128i v_ge = _mm_cmpge_epu8(va, vb);
    __m128i v_le = _mm_cmple_epu8(va, vb);
    __m128i v_gt = _mm_cmpgt_epu8(va, vb);
    __m128i v_lt = _mm_cmplt_epu8(va, vb);

    printf("va   = %4vhhu\n", va);
    printf("vb   = %4vhhu\n", vb);
    printf("v_ge = %4vhhu\n", v_ge);
    printf("v_le = %4vhhu\n", v_le);
    printf("v_gt = %4vhhu\n", v_gt);
    printf("v_lt = %4vhhu\n", v_lt);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall _mm_cmplt_epu8.c && ./a.out 
va   =    0    0    1    1    1  127  127  127  128  128  128  254  254  254  255  255
vb   =    0  255    0    1  255    0  127  255    0  128  255    0  254  255    0  255
v_ge =  255    0  255  255    0  255  255    0  255  255    0  255  255    0  255  255
v_le =  255  255    0  255  255    0  255  255    0  255  255    0  255  255    0  255
v_gt =    0    0  255    0    0  255    0    0  255    0    0  255    0    0  255    0
v_lt =    0  255    0    0  255    0    0  255    0    0  255    0    0  255    0    0
```

Answer (score 7):

The other answers got me thinking of a simpler method to answer the specific question more directly:

To simply detect clamping, do saturating and non-saturating additions, and compare the results.

```
__m128i m1 = _mm_loadu_si128(/* 16 8-bit unsigned integers */);
__m128i m2 = _mm_loadu_si128(/* 16 8-bit unsigned integers */);

__m128i m1m2_sat = _mm_adds_epu8(m1, m2);
__m128i m1m2_wrap = _mm_add_epi8(m1, m2);
__m128i non_clipped = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(m1m2_sat, m1m2_wrap);
```

So that's just two instructions beyond the `adds`, and one of them can run in parallel with the `adds`.  So the `non_clipped` mask is ready one cycle after the addition result.  (Potentially 3 instructions (an extra movdqa) without AVX 3-operand non-destructive vector ops.)

If the non-saturating add result is 0xFF, it will match the saturating-add result, and be detected as not clipping.  This is why it's different from just checking the output of the saturating add for 0xFF bytes.

Comment: This is a more "holistic" answer!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to compare unsigned bytes: add `0x80` and compare them as signed ones.

```
__m128i _mm_cmplt_epu8(__m128i a, __m128i b) {
    __m128i as = _mm_add_epi8(a, _mm_set1_epi8((char)0x80));
    __m128i bs = _mm_add_epi8(b, _mm_set1_epi8((char)0x80));
    return _mm_cmplt_epi8(as, bs);
}
```

I don't think it is very efficient, but it works, and it may be useful in some cases. Also, you can use *xor* instead of addition if you want.
In some cases you can even do bidirectional range checking at once, i.e. compare a value with both lower and upper bounds. To do so, align the lower bound with `0x80`, similar to what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095534/556899) does.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation of comparison of 8-bit unsigned integer:

```
    inline __m128i NotEqual8u(__m128i a, __m128i b)
    {
        return _mm_andnot_si128(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(a, b), _mm_set1_epi8(-1));
    }

    inline __m128i Greater8u(__m128i a, __m128i b)
    {
        return _mm_andnot_si128(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_min_epu8(a, b), a), _mm_set1_epi8(-1));
    }

    inline __m128i GreaterOrEqual8u(__m128i a, __m128i b)
    {
        return _mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_max_epu8(a, b), a);
    }

    inline __m128i Lesser8u(__m128i a, __m128i b)
    {
        return _mm_andnot_si128(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_max_epu8(a, b), a), _mm_set1_epi8(-1));
    }

    inline __m128i LesserOrEqual8u(__m128i a, __m128i b)
    {
        return _mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_min_epu8(a, b), a);
    }
```