# Strange behaviour when comparing in SSE

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I don't get the error in my code. I try to compare a buffer of unsigned char values to a constant. Then I want to store 1 or 0 depending on the comparison. Here is my code (in a structure):

```
void operator()(const uint8* src, int32 swidth, int32 sheight, uint8* dst, uint8 value) {
   uint8 t[16];
   __m128i v_one = _mm_set1_epi8((uint8)1);
   __m128i v_value = _mm_set1_epi8(value);

   printf("value = %d\n", value);
   SHOW(t, v_one);
   SHOW(t, v_value);
   std::cout << "****" << std::endl;

   for (int32 i = 0; i < sheight; ++i) {
      const uint8* sdata = src + i * swidth;
      uint8* ddata = dst + i * swidth;
      int32 j = 0;
      for ( ; j <= swidth - 16; j += 16) {
         __m128i s = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(sdata + j));
         __m128i mask = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(s, v_value);

         SHOW(t, s);
         SHOW(t, mask);
         std::cout << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

My first line are what I would expect:

```
value = 100
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

But then my comparison are wrong:

```
214 100 199 203 232  50  85 195  70 141 121 160  93 130 242 233
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255   0   0   0   0   0
```

And I really don't get where the mistakes are.

The `SHOW` macro is:

```
#define SHOW(t, r)                  \
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)t, r); \
  printf("%3d", (int32)t[0]);       \
  for (int32 k = 1; k < 16; ++k)    \
    printf(" %3d", (int32)t[k]);    \
  printf("\n")
```

Comment: to me; the most obvious mistake is that you're not using a std::vector (or std::array) because it means you can't; looking at the function; know if the memory being passed to it is valid.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing the elements in your `s` array with your `value` array.

All the values in the `value` array are 100.
You have a mix of values in your `s` array.

However, `_mm_cmpgt_epi8` works on *signed* values and as these are bytes it considers values from -128 to +127.

So the only possible values that are > 100 are values in the range 101 to 127.

As you've only got 1 value in that range (121) thats the only one which has its mask set.

To see this, change `uint8 t[16];` to `int8 t[16];` and you should get a more expected result.

Comment: That's right. I found this question explaining how to compare unsigned char for those interested. Thanks ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824300/optimal-sse-unsigned-8-bit-compare