# AVX2 expand contiguous elements to a sparse vector based on a condition? (like AVX512 VPEXPANDD)

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx2

Does anyone know how to vectorize the following code?

```
uint32_t r[8];
uint16_t* ptr;
for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    if (r[j] < C)
        r[j] = *(ptr++);
```

It's basically a masked gather operation. The auto-vectorizer can't deal with this. If ptr was a uint32_t* it should be directly realizable with [_mm256_mask_i32gather_epi32](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523959). But even then how do you generate the correct index vector? And wouldn't it be faster to just use a packed load and shuffling the result anyway (requiring a similar index vector)?

Comment: If you had AVX512F, you'd want to use [`vpexpandd ymm1{k1}, ymm2`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPEXPANDD) to expand contiguous source data according to a compare-mask, with merge-masking (instead of `{z}` zero masking).  @wim's answer implements that using `pdep`, because AVX2 doesn't have expand / compress vector instructions.  It would be more efficient if you could zero elements of `r[]` instead of leaving them unmodified.

Comment: Retitled to better match the actual question (and answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated answer: The main piece of code has been rewritten as a function and a solution 
suitable for AMD processors has been added.

As Peter Cordes mentioned in the comments, the AVX-512 instruction `vpexpandd` would be useful here.
The functions `_mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2_BMI()` and `_mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2()` below more
or less emulate this instruction. The AVX2_BMI variant is suitable for Intel Haswell processors and newer.
The `_mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2()` function is suitable for AMD processors with a slow or 
lacking `pdep` instruction, such as the Ryzen processor. 
In this function a few instructions with high throughput, 
such as shifts and simple arithmetic operations, are used instead of the `pdep` instruction. 
Another possibility for AMD processors would be 
to process only 4 elements at the time, and use a tiny (16 element) lookup-table to retrieve 
the shuf_mask.

Below these two functions it is shown how these can be used to vectorize your scalar code

The answer uses a similar idea as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36951611/2439725) answer by Peter Cordes, 
which discusses left packing based on a mask. In that answer the BMI2 
instruction `pext` is used to compute the permutation vector. 
Here we use the `pdep` instruction instead, to compute the permutation vector.
Function `_mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2()` finds the permutation vector 
in a different way by computing
a [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) on the `r<C` mask.

Because of the unsigned `uint32_t`, I used Paul R's idea for `epu32` unsigned comparisons.

```
/*     gcc -O3 -m64 -Wall -mavx2 -march=broadwell mask_expand_avx.c     */
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

__m256i _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2_BMI(__m256i src, __m256i mask, __m256i insert_vals, int* nonz){ 
    /* Scatter the insert_vals to the positions indicated by mask.                                                                    */               
    /* Blend the src with these scattered insert_vals.                                                                                */
    /* Return also the number of nonzeros in mask (which is inexpensive here                                                          */
    /* because _mm256_movemask_epi8(mask) has to be computed anyway.)                                                                          */
    /* This code is suitable for Intel Haswell and newer processors.                                                                  */
    /* This code is less suitble for AMD Ryzen processors, due to the                                                                 */
    /* slow pdep instruction on those processors, see _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2                                                   */
    uint32_t all_indx         = 0x76543210;
    uint32_t mask_int32       = _mm256_movemask_epi8(mask);                           /* Packed mask of 8 nibbles                     */
    uint32_t wanted_indx      = _pdep_u32(all_indx, mask_int32);                      /* Select the right nibbles from all_indx       */
    uint64_t expand_indx      = _pdep_u64(wanted_indx, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F);           /* Expand the nibbles to bytes                  */
    __m128i  shuf_mask_8bit   = _mm_cvtsi64_si128(expand_indx);                       /* Move to AVX-128 register                     */
    __m256i  shuf_mask        = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(shuf_mask_8bit);                 /* Expand bytes to 32-bit integers              */
    __m256i  insert_vals_exp  = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(insert_vals, shuf_mask);  /* Expand insert_vals to the right positions    */
    __m256i  dst              = _mm256_blendv_epi8(src, insert_vals_exp, mask);       /* src is replaced by insert_vals_exp at the postions indicated by mask */
             *nonz            = _mm_popcnt_u32(mask_int32) >> 2;
             return dst;
}


__m256i _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2(__m256i src, __m256i mask, __m256i insert_vals, int* nonz){ 
    /* Scatter the insert_vals to the positions indicated by mask.                                                                    */               
    /* Blend the src with these scattered insert_vals.                                                                                */
    /* Return also the number of nonzeros in mask.                                                                                    */
    /* This code is an alternative for the _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2_BMI function.                                                */
    /* In contrast to that code, this code doesn't use the BMI instruction pdep.                                                      */
    /* Therefore, this code is suitable for AMD processors.                                                                            */
    __m128i  mask_lo          = _mm256_castsi256_si128(mask);                      
    __m128i  mask_hi          = _mm256_extracti128_si256(mask, 1);                  
    __m128i  mask_hi_lo       = _mm_packs_epi32(mask_lo, mask_hi);                    /* Compressed 128-bits (8 x 16-bits) mask       */
             *nonz            = _mm_popcnt_u32(_mm_movemask_epi8(mask_hi_lo)) >> 1;
    __m128i  prefix_sum       = mask_hi_lo;
    __m128i  prefix_sum_shft  = _mm_slli_si128(prefix_sum, 2);                        /* The permutation vector is based on the       */
             prefix_sum       = _mm_add_epi16(prefix_sum, prefix_sum_shft);           /* Prefix sum of the mask.                      */
             prefix_sum_shft  = _mm_slli_si128(prefix_sum, 4);
             prefix_sum       = _mm_add_epi16(prefix_sum, prefix_sum_shft);
             prefix_sum_shft  = _mm_slli_si128(prefix_sum, 8);
             prefix_sum       = _mm_add_epi16(prefix_sum, prefix_sum_shft);
    __m128i  shuf_mask_16bit  = _mm_sub_epi16(_mm_set1_epi16(-1), prefix_sum);
    __m256i  shuf_mask        = _mm256_cvtepu16_epi32(shuf_mask_16bit);               /* Expand 16-bit integers to 32-bit integers    */
    __m256i  insert_vals_exp  = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(insert_vals, shuf_mask);  /* Expand insert_vals to the right positions    */
    __m256i  dst              = _mm256_blendv_epi8(src, insert_vals_exp, mask);       /* src is replaced by insert_vals_exp at the postions indicated by mask */
             return dst;
}


/* Unsigned integer compare _mm256_cmplt_epu32 doesn't exist                                                    */
/* The next two lines are based on Paul R's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32945715/2439725                 */
#define _mm256_cmpge_epu32(a, b) _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(_mm256_max_epu32(a, b), a)
#define _mm256_cmplt_epu32(a, b) _mm256_xor_si256(_mm256_cmpge_epu32(a, b), _mm256_set1_epi32(-1))

int print_input(uint32_t* r, uint32_t C, uint16_t* ptr);
int print_output(uint32_t* r, uint16_t* ptr);

int main(){
    int       nonz;
    uint32_t  r[8]        = {6, 3, 1001, 2, 1002, 7, 5, 1003};
    uint32_t  r_new[8];
    uint32_t  C           = 9;
    uint16_t* ptr         = malloc(8*2);  /* allocate 16 bytes for 8 uint16_t's */
              ptr[0] = 11; ptr[1] = 12; ptr[2] = 13;ptr[3] = 14; ptr[4] = 15; ptr[5] = 16; ptr[6] = 17; ptr[7] = 18;
    uint16_t* ptr_new;

              printf("Test values:\n");
              print_input(r,C,ptr);

    __m256i   src         = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *)r);
    __m128i   ins         = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)ptr);
    __m256i   insert_vals = _mm256_cvtepu16_epi32(ins);
    __m256i   mask_C      = _mm256_cmplt_epu32(src,_mm256_set1_epi32(C));   


              printf("Output _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2_BMI:\n");
    __m256i   output      = _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2_BMI(src, mask_C, insert_vals, &nonz);
                            _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i *)r_new,output);
              ptr_new     = ptr + nonz;
              print_output(r_new,ptr_new);              


              printf("Output _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2:\n");
              output      = _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2(src, mask_C, insert_vals, &nonz);
                            _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i *)r_new,output);
              ptr_new     = ptr + nonz;
              print_output(r_new,ptr_new);              


              printf("Output scalar loop:\n");
              for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                  if (r[j] < C)
                      r[j] = *(ptr++);
              print_output(r,ptr);              

              return 0;
}

int print_input(uint32_t* r, uint32_t C, uint16_t* ptr){
    printf("r[0]..r[7]        =     %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  \n",r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6],r[7]);
    printf("Threshold value C =     %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  \n",C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C);
    printf("ptr[0]..ptr[7]    =     %4hu  %4hu  %4hu  %4hu  %4hu  %4hu  %4hu  %4hu  \n\n",ptr[0],ptr[1],ptr[2],ptr[3],ptr[4],ptr[5],ptr[6],ptr[7]);
    return 0;
}

int print_output(uint32_t* r, uint16_t* ptr){
    printf("r[0]..r[7]        =     %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  \n",r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6],r[7]);
    printf("ptr               = %p \n\n",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./a.out
Test values:
r[0]..r[7]        =        6     3  1001     2  1002     7     5  1003  
Threshold value C =        9     9     9     9     9     9     9     9  
ptr[0]..ptr[7]    =       11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18  

Output _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2_BMI:
r[0]..r[7]        =       11    12  1001    13  1002    14    15  1003  
ptr               = 0x92c01a 

Output _mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2:
r[0]..r[7]        =       11    12  1001    13  1002    14    15  1003  
ptr               = 0x92c01a 

Output scalar loop:
r[0]..r[7]        =       11    12  1001    13  1002    14    15  1003  
ptr               = 0x92c01a
```

Comment: Note that the `pdep` instruction is supported on Intel Haswell processors or newer. It is also supported on the AMD Zen/Ryzen CPU's, but the throughput and latency numbers are very poor on that architecture: both are 18 cycles.

Comment: Interesting that you need a `vpmovzx` before the compare so you can get 4 bits per element instead of 2 from `vpmovmskb`.  I feel like there should be a way to use only one `pdep`.  But I guess it would cost an extra instruction somewhere else to unpack the 4-bit indices to 8-bit.  And I don't see a way to use an integer multiply to directly replace a `pdep`.  If optimizing specifically for AMD, you might avoid pdep altogether, or unpack the compare to qword before `vpmovmskb`, using `vpmovsxwq` (after doing the compare with 16-bit elements)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, but note that the result of `vpmovzx` is not used as an input for the compare. So, unfortunately, the mask is 8x32-bit instead of 8x16 bit. Indeed it is possible to get rid of one `pdep`, for example in the same way as described in my [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932240/avx2-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pack-left-based-on-a-mask/36951611#comment71177339_36951611). Christoph's remark on that comment and the subsequent discussion is also relevant here.

Comment: Ah right, easy to get mixed up without meaningful variable names.  I forgot which thing was narrower.  I guess we could use a narrower shuffle on the 16-bit elements before expanding to a 256b vector.  But building a control vector for `vpshufb` is harder, and until AVX512 there are no 16-bit granularity word-shuffles with variable controls.  (If AVX512F didn't have `vpexpandd`, you could use `vpermw` here with indices spread out into a 256b vector, to do the `vpmovzxwd` work at the same time).  Anyway, avoiding `vpermd ymm` is worth thinking about for AMD, where `vpermd` is multiple uops.

Comment: @PeterCordes For AMD it is probably best to process only 4 elements at the time, and use a tiny (16 element) lookup-table to retrieve the `shuf_mask`. This avoids both the expensive `pdep` and `vpermd ymm` instructions.

Comment: Yeah, I bet you're right.  Good point.  On Ryzen there's only a bit of extra front-end throughput to be gained from using 256-bit OPs (like 6 uops per clock instead of 5 if you use only single-uop instructions).