# What are the differences between the compress and expand instructions in AVX-512?

Tags: assembly, x86, simd, avx512

I was studying the expand and compress operations from the [Intel intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=MMX,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512&expand=21,3104,91,3897,3900,3922,3944,4745,4754,4787,4798,4807,4816,4760,4766,4772,4778,2945,4029,3922,2873,1164,1166,1165,2203,1176,2202&text=expand). I'm confused about these two concepts:

For `__m128d _mm_mask_expand_pd (__m128d src, __mmask8 k, __m128d a) == vexpandpd`

> Load contiguous active double-precision (64-bit) floating-point elements from a (those with their respective bit set in mask k), and store the results in dst using writemask k (elements are copied from src when the corresponding mask bit is not set).

For `__m128d _mm_mask_compress_pd (__m128d src, __mmask8 k, __m128d a) == vcompresspd`

> Contiguously store the active double-precision (64-bit) floating-point elements in a (those with their respective bit set in writemask k) to dst, and pass through the remaining elements from src.

Is there any clearer description or anyone who can explain more?

Comment: They're the vector equivalent of BMI2 [`pdep`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PDEP.html) and `pext`.  See my AVX512 answer on [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240) for how to use them.  (And for how to use `pext` / `pdep` to generate shuffle masks on the fly for AVX2.)

Comment: Note that Peter Cordes' left packing answer shows how to emulate instruction `vcompressps`. On the other hand, the function `_mm256_mask_expand_epi32_AVX2_BMI` in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178813) emulates the `vpexpandd` instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I _wish_ they were the vectorized versions of `pdep` and `pext`! The main difference is that `pdep` and `pext` are bit-wise, but even for future version of AVX-512, the compress instructions are at their finest only byte-wise. I doubt we will see the bit-wise versions any time soon: the hardware to do such bit granularity compression is considerable and doesn't overlap much with the other shuffle units.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These instructions implement the APL operators `\` (expand) and `/` (compress).  *Expand* takes a bit mask α of some *m* ≥ *n* bits of which *n* are set and an array ω of *n* numbers and returns a vector of *m* numbers with the numbers from ω inserted into the places indicated by α and the rest set to zero.  For example,

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 \ 2 3 4
```

returns

```
0 2 3 0 4 0
```

The `_mm_mask_expand_pd` instruction implements this operator for fixed *m* = 8.

The *compress* operation undos the effect of the *expand* operation, i.e. it uses a bit mask α to select entries from ω and stores these entries contiguously to  memory.