# AVX2 64-bit unsigned integer comparison

Tags: c, integer, compare, avx2

I'm trying to compare two `__m256i` (4 packed 64-bit integers). To do so, I use the [_mm256_cmpgt_epi64](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523924) function.

The function works as expected except for a few comparisons, as if the function did not consider the largest bit of the 64-bit integer. As shown below in the second and third comparisons.

Here a MCVE, where I expect each 64-bit integer from `a` to be larger than its peer from `b` (thus `cp` should be `0xFFF...FFF`):

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// gcc mcve.c -mavx2 -madx && ./a.out

int print_avx2_hex256(__m256i ymm)
{
    const size_t n = sizeof(__m256i) / sizeof(u_int64_t);
    u_int64_t buffer[n];
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)buffer, ymm);
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        printf("%016"PRIx64" ", buffer[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int compare(__m256i a, __m256i b)
{
    __m256i cp = _mm256_cmpgt_epi64(a,b);

    print_avx2_hex256(cp); // Comparison
    print_avx2_hex256(a);
    print_avx2_hex256(b);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    u_int64_t _a[4] = {0xf, 0xf000000000000000, 0xd00000000000000d, 0x0f00000000000000};
    u_int64_t _b[4] = {0x2, 0x2000000000000000, 0x2000000000000002, 0x0200000000000000};

    __m256i a   = _mm256_setr_epi64x(_a[0], _a[1], _a[2], _a[3]);
    __m256i b   = _mm256_setr_epi64x(_b[0], _b[1], _b[2], _b[3]);

    compare(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

However my output is as follow (in order `cp`, `a`, `b`):

```
ffffffffffffffff 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffffffffffffffff 
000000000000000f f000000000000000 d00000000000000d 0f00000000000000 
0000000000000002 2000000000000000 2000000000000002 0200000000000000
```

I'm not familiar with the Intel Intrinsics functions, so if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that `_mm256_cmpgt_epi64` compares *signed* integers, so if you set the most significant bit on one of the i64s, it is considered negative. For instance, `0xf000000000000000` is negative, `0x2000000000000000` is not, and `_mm256_cmpgt_epi64` (rightly) tells you that the latter is greater.

It doesn't look like there's a strictly equivalent function that compares unsigned ints, but you can use `_mm256_cmpgt_epu64_mask`, which returns an `__mmask8` bit-field.

EDIT: forgot to mention that `_mm256_cmpgt_epu64_mask` requires AVX512, which may not be available to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I didn't think about that. Can you just tell me how to print/use a `__mask8` variable ? I can't find any documentation about it. Indeed can't have AVX512 :$

Comment: An `__mmask8` is a type alias for an `unsigned char`, so using the `%x` printf formatter should do.

Comment: I indeed get an error if I try using the cmp_epu64_mask function. `error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm256_cmpgt_epu64_mask’: target specific option mismatch` It seems that it can't run on my computer, thanks anyway for identifying the problem !

Comment: To compare as unsigned integers you can add `0x8000000000000000` to both `a` and `b`. and use the signed compare, see for example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33173643).

Comment: @wim: Or better, XOR instead of ADD (runs on more ports on Haswell/Broadwell).  It's the top bit, so add = add-without-carry.

Comment: Is there a single instruction solution how to emulate non existing _mm256_cmpgt_epu64? Or is the xor/add so fast that I should not worry about? (I can not use AVX-512 _mm256_cmpgt_epu64_mask)

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your issue!