# How to compare a register with a hexadecimal

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm writing a program in assembly that is suppose to take the value of a key press, store it in a register and see what the value is.

I have managed to save 0x00000002 after pressing the key 2, into the register I wanted to save it in which is called "r1".

Now this is where I get lost. I'm now trying to compare this to some hexadecimals, so that I then can get know what the value is and use it in an other function. This is how my code looks like:

```
cmp r1, #0x30
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x31
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x32
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x33
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x34
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x35
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x36
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x37
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x38
beq savekey
cmp r1, #0x39
beq savekey
```

The expected result of this I thought would be that it would go in to the function "savekey" whenever it recognize that it was a number. However this never happens and it just skips all of them.

How could I do the comparison between the register and the hexadecimal different so it will work correctly? And is there any simpler way I can write this so I don't have to write a case for every single digit?

Comment: instead of a series of `cmp`s like that, you should use a jump table. But if you just want to get 2 from 0x32 then just subtract 0x30 from it. And to check if a value is withing the range [0x30, 0x39] then [there's a nice trick that needs only a single comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17095324/995714)

Comment: ARM has bgt / blt for range checks: you don't need a chain of BEQ for contiguous values that all jump to the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a *range check* in assembler.  In 'C' this would be something like, `if(x >= '0' && x < ((int)'9')+1) savekey();`.  The equivalent ARM assembler would be like,

```
  cmp r1, 0x30
  blo bad_value
  cmp r1, 0x3A
  bhs bad_value
  b   save_key
```

You need to have a branch to the bad case unless you use a temporary register.  The you can subtract the base (0x30), treat the temporary as `unsigned` and test for the higher case.  Here is something like that,

```
 sub r2, r1, 0x30         @ low values will wrap to a high unsigned value
 cmp r2, 10               @ in range (0-9)?
 blo save_key
 ; bad/error handling here.
```

As others have noted, your ASCII value might already need this subtraction to convert to a *binary* or machine value.

Comment: Note, the above is for converting ASCII decimal to binary.  Note sure if the user input is decimal or hexidecimal.  Also, you need to multiply/shift the converted single ASCII value to get a full binary value.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it through replacing for example #0x38 with #8. However I'm still wondering how to simplify the code.

Comment: Did you already `sub r1, #'0'`` to convert a digit from ASCII to integer?  `#0x38` is the right syntax for decimal `56` = hex `0x38` as an immediate.